# get a list of files and directories with full path in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to get full path of both the files and directories from a directory. I tried using find but unable to get result.

when I used find /home/demo -type f it only lists files and find /home/demo -type d only lists directories.

Is there a way to get both using Find?

Comment: can you show what you already tried?

Comment: Does just `find` not work? What is your expected result, and what's wrong with the output of `find`?

Comment: when I used find /home/demo -type f it only lists files and find /home/demo -type d only lists directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the absolute path of a directory. As an example for the current directory:

```
find "`pwd`"
```

`pwd` shows full path of current directory. `` ` ` `` summons a subshell in which output can be used as an argument to the command.

A literal example can be:

```
find /home/user
```

Update: You can use `-o` to explicitly target both files and directories. Doing `find` without an option may include other types besides the two.

```
find /home/user \( -type f -o -type d \)
```

Note: `-or` is synonymous but may not work in other versions of `find` since it's not POSIX compliant.

Comment: I tried it but, when I used find /home/demo -type f it only lists files and find /home/demo -type d only lists directories. Is there a way to get both of them?

Comment: @girishkumar Without any option, any type of file would be presented but I guess that's not what you want. You can use `-o` for what you wanted.

Comment: The second one worked find /home/demo gave the list of files as well directories. Thank you.

Comment: @konsolebox There is no reason for the parentheses in your last version

Comment: @BroSlow Yes granting the user doesn't add more options.